# If g:Y→Z is a continuous injection, is the map f:X→Y closed if g∘f is a closed map?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

I already proved 1 and 2 and I'm trying to figure out problem 3. I think the answer is true. If we just repeat the same proof using closed sets instead of open sets, I don't see what the difference is. Say, for problem 2, we assume U is a closed set in X. Then $f(U)=g^{−1}(g(f(U)))=g^{−1}(g∘f(U))$ because g is injective. Is there any problem here?

Comment: No problems. The proof works for 3) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof purely relies on a set theory fact and not an any topological fact, so that same proof will work for both open and closed maps.

Comment: How can it not rely on "any topological fact" when the very core of the question is whether functions are closed or open? That seems very topological to me.

Comment: @Arthur you don’t actually use that $U$ is open or closed.

Comment: Then maybe you could be a bit more specific that it is the equality $f(U)=g^{−1}(g(f(U)))=g^{−1}(g∘f(U))$ that doesn't rely on topology. Not the entire proof? Because the equality doesn't let you conclude anything about open or closed maps unless you assume something about $U$.

Comment: @Arthur you could just as well use this proof for "P-preseerving maps" where P is any property you like (measurable, being linearly independent etc.)